# To calculate % in hive query

Tags: hive, hiveql

with the below query i can able to get the approved transaction for per client on per day basis.

```
select 
    q1.client_id, 
    q1.receive_day, 
    count(q1.client_id) as cnt 
from 
    (select * from sale where response=00) q1 
group by 
    q1.client_id, q1.receive_day
```

I want to get the approval %, i.e. the approval_per, is 100*(count(client_id)/response), while count(client_id) is the number of clients for the approved transaction.

Response is a count of whole response including all the values (approved and not approved) . I can get the response by `select count(response) from sale` , but how to make it here for calculating % in the same query is the problem am facing now. I tried out some options as it didn't work , reached user group.

so my expected output format is client_id,receive_day,count(client_id),approval_per.

Any of your help are really appreciated

Thanks & Regards,

dti

Answer (score 0):

You could simply add another subquery which calculates that count.  Also for the query you have now it seems unnecessary to have that subquery (q1).

I also make the assumption that you want your percentage should be the percentage of transactions each client is responsible for.  I.e. number of transactions for given client divided by number of total transactions.

```
SELECT 
    s.client_id, 
    s.receive_day, 
    count(s.client_id) as cnt,
    100 * (count(s.client_id) / q1.total)  
FROM 
    sale s,
    (select count(*) total from sale) q1
WHERE
    response = 00
GROUP BY 
    s.client_id, s.receive_day
```

Comment: How can you use q1.total in select while it is not in group by?

Comment: I didn't actually run this hive query, so I may have forgotten that.